When sending email through bash script in cron it goes to root
Edit: I'm so embarrassed. I had a typo in the script name. So the email was crontab trying to tell me it couldn't find the script.
So it was trying to email root because the cronjob failed and I set the mailto to my email address and realized my mistake.
So I have a bash script and if I execute it normally it will send to an email address that I have specified in the script. However, if I put this in a crontab and run that as root it will send it from root and to root even though the mail command I pass sets the from and to address. What is causing that to happen?
I'm using the mail command to send the email in the script.
echo $EMAIL_BODY | mail -s "Test" "From:user@domain.com" "user2@domain.com"

Also if I run the script manually as root it works as I would expect so i'm not sure why only through cron it is doing this.
# Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
# command to install the new version when you edit this file
# and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also have username fields,
# that none of the other crontabs do.

SHELL=/bin/sh
# You can also override PATH, but by default, newer versions inherit it from the environment
#PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# Example of job definition:
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7) OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  * user-name command to be executed
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
#
50 14   * * *   root    /etc/adminscripts/mysql_backup.sh


Here is the output of the postfix:
May 28 14:50:02 servername postfix/qmgr[1608494]: C2129149CD: from=<root@domain.com>, size=609, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
May 28 14:50:02 servername postfix/smtp[1683687]: C2129149CD: to=<root@domain.com>, orig_to=<root>, relay=smtp-relay.gmail.com[172.253.115.28]:587, delay=1.2, delays=0.04/0.16/0.79/0.21, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK  1716922202 6a1803df08f44-6ac16286af0sm14719646d6.61 - gsmtp)
May 28 14:50:03 servername postfix/qmgr[1608494]: C2129149CD: removed


Don't forget to double quote your variables when you use them, so echo "$EMAIL_BODY"

What's your actual crontab entry, and in which file have you put it?

What do the postfix logs tell you?

Please [edit] your question to provide additional information. Don't put replies or updates in the comments

Add your cronjob to your question (no comment).

Are you sure the email message logs relate to the message you tried to send, and not to some error message that needs to be returned to root? What does the message sent to the Gmail account say?

it definitely tries to send it to root@domain.com but that email address doesn't actually exist. I just don't understand why it's doing that. I saw this bounce message when I search for emails.
Bounced
The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try double-checking the recipient's email address for typos or unnecessary spaces.

This wasn't working because cron couldn't find the script because I had a typo. So it was trying to email root the output of the cron execution. Probably good practice to have a mailto set in these situations so you know when the cron execution fails.
Here is the fixed crontab:
# Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
# command to install the new version when you edit this file
# and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also have username fields,
# that none of the other crontabs do.

SHELL=/bin/sh
# You can also override PATH, but by default, newer versions inherit it from the environment
#PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# Example of job definition:
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7) OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  * user-name command to be executed
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
#
50 14   * * *   root    /etc/adminscripts/mysql-backup.sh

